# Remove the "Now Playing" feature from Winamp

Tags: winamp

Since I updated to the latest version of Winamp (5.55) each time I restore (unminimize) from the system tray, the media library panel goes to "Now Playing".

Not only is that really annoying since it changes from the media view I want, but it also displays lots of very distracting advertising, not to mention that I really don't give a stuff about the information it shows me. Is there a way to remove this altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to stop the behaviour for switching to Now Playing:

```
Options -> Notifications -> Open Now Playing On Click
```

Answer (score 3):

Preferences -> Plugins -> Media Library -> Now Playing -> Click "Uninstall"

Comment: It keeps coming back!!

Comment: after uninstalling it? Thats very, well, odd. Maybe remove winamp altogether and reinstall as previously mentioned?

Comment: even deleting `winamp/plugins/ml_nowplaying.dll` doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you considered taking your PC to an exorcist?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Winamp, you can choose not to install the "Now Playing" feature. My suggestion is to just reinstall Winamp and unckeck this option.

Answer (score -1):

Options -> Notifications -> Never show